# Policy Falsified error in Java Webservice using Weblogic and Layer 7 randomly

Tags: java, web-services, certificate, weblogic

I have an issue that is in my opinion weird in that it only happens randomly. The error is a policy falsified warning. I am leaning on Layer 7 being the culprit. In the dev environment where certificates are not used, it works 100% of the time. Introducing certs lead to the issue, and in dev we disabled all but one node in web logic and it works 100% of the time. When I enable all the nodes, and enable the certificate with correct keystore and keystore password on the enviornment, I get the error SOMETIMES. I can't explain why, it fails and passes on all three nodes seemingly randomly, and in the Layer 7 audit I see the requests coming in. What could possibly cause this? Here is the message from Layer 7:

```
    Node           : intssgn1w1
Time           : 20150724 07:16:16.346
Severity       : WARNING
Request Id     : 0000014e65301aff-67c783a
Message        : Message was not processed: Assertion Falsified (600)
Audit Record ID: 4820934462

Event Type     : Message Summary
Client IP      : 10.2.110.226
Service        : correctServiceAddresss/name
Operation      : onboardPerson
Rqst Length    : <Not Saved>
Resp Length    : <Not Saved>
Resp Status    : 0
Resp Time      : 4ms
User ID        : 4799889408
User Name      : cert-user
Auth Method    : HTTPS Client Cert'
```

On a passing request to the same node/enviornment:

```
Node           : intssgn1w1
Time           : 20150724 07:10:06.447
Severity       : WARNING
Request Id     : 0000014e65301aff-67c65e5
Message        : Message processed successfully
Audit Record ID: 4820934444

Event Type     : Message Summary
Client IP      : 10.2.110.226
Service        : correctServiceAddresss/name
Operation      : onboardPerson
Rqst Length    : <Not Saved>
Resp Length    : <Not Saved>
Resp Status    : 200
Resp Time      : 1107ms
User ID        : 4799889408
User Name      : cert-user
Auth Method    : HTTPS Client Cert
```

I have no idea why. If anyone has better experience with Layer 7 or Web logic and can point me in some directions I will follow up on them. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to figure this one out, and for the sake of questions going unanswered for future people with this problem, I hope this helps.
The issue was with the plan.xml file not properly syncing up all of the nodes in Weblogic server. On each deploy, the first node would deploy successfully and the botch the other nodes deploy because of the problems in the plan.xml. Layer 7 had nothing to do with it, only that it gives the same policy falsified generic error.

If you are experiencing this problem, you can verify this will fix by doing the following:
1) access each node on Weblogic server console.
2) In each node access the web service that is throwing the error
NOTE: At this point I was done, the installs on other nodes were corrupt and I got the error pop that would not allow me to enter them
3) Check status of the services are up and running

If you are kicked out like I was, try redeploying. If this does not fix it, but as I said the first node is working, the plan.xml is most likely the culprit.